# Configure object mapper to replace values with lower case

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have a class Diff that looks like so:

```
public class Diff {

    private String path;
    private String value;
    private Operation operation;

    public enum Operation {
        ADD, REPLACE, REMOVE
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

I want to create a json node using the following call:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.valueToTree(diffObject);
```

If I have a Diff like so:

```
Diff diff = new Diff();
diff.setPath("/path");
diff.setValue("value");
diff.setOperation(Operation.REPLACE);
```

Doing:

```
mapper.valueToTree(diff);
```

will return:

```
"{"path":"/path", "value":"value","operation":"REPLACE"}"
```

I need the word "operation" to just be "op", though.  Supposedly, there's a way to configure ObjectMapper in a way as to where when it reads "operation", it will translate it to just "op", but I have no idea how to do it.  Anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @JsonProperty annotation

```
public static class Diff {

    private String path;
    private String value;

    @JsonProperty("op")
    private Operation operation;
}
```

**[UPDATE]**
Because you dont have access to the class, can you use ByteBuddy to modify the class a bit ? :)

For example:

```
@Test
public void byteBuddyManipulation() throws JsonProcessingException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    AnnotationDescription annotationDescription = AnnotationDescription.Builder.forType(JsonProperty.class)
            .define("value", "op")
            .make();

    Class<? extends Diff> clazz = new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Diff.class)
            .defineField("operation", Diff.Operation.class)
            .annotateField(annotationDescription)
            .make()
            .load(Diff.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION)
            .getLoaded();

    Diff diffUpdated = clazz.newInstance();
    diffUpdated.setOperation(Diff.Operation.ADD);

    objectMapper.valueToTree(diffUpdated);   //returns "op":"ADD"
}
```

**[UPDATE 2]**
Or simply create subclass of Diff and shadow the operation field

```
public static class YourDiff extends Diff {
    @JsonProperty("op")
    private Operation operation;

    @Override public Operation getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    @Override public void setOperation(Operation operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds neat, but my Diff class is in a separate module from where I'm working, and it doesn't have access to any of the Json dependencies.  In other words, the operations I need to do must occur outside of the class